# list.js weird error with content in chrome

Tags: list, google-chrome, listjs

i have experienced a problem with the plugin "list.js". And i don't know how to solve it. 
I have been troubleshooting for a long time now, and i can't find any errors.

```
var options = {
  valueNames: [ 'name', 'description', 'category' ],
};

var featureList = new List('lovely-things-list', options);

$('#filter-jyls').click(function() {
  featureList.filter(function(item) {
    if (item.values().category == "Jyl") {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
  return false;
});

$('#filter-fyns').click(function() {
  featureList.filter(function(item) {
    if (item.values().category == "Fyn") {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
  return false;
});
$('#filter-none').click(function() {
  featureList.filter();
  return false;
});

$('#filter-sjas').click(function() {
  featureList.filter(function(item) {
    if (item.values().category == "Sja") {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
  return false;
});

$('#filter-stors').click(function() {
  featureList.filter(function(item) {
    if (item.values().category == "Stor") {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
  return false;
});

$('#filter-lols').click(function() {
  featureList.filter(function(item) {
    if (item.values().category == "Lol") {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Here is a [fiddly](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6Ffp) to my problem:

Click on the button:
"jyl (click me a lot, - i crash)"
And you will se how the list jumps around. It should work like the button:
"Lol (click me i am fine too)"

As you can see, it list the content very weird and it jumps around. 
This problem happens in chrome, but not in IE. 
Any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry here is the link:
http://jsfiddle.net/Z6Ffp/`

Comment: Weird indeed. Seems to work with only 4 "Jyl" elements. As soon as you add the 5th in it breaks http://jsfiddle.net/Z6Ffp/11/

Comment: Looks like a bug in list.js itself - may be worth contacting the author